# how to impove image processing in android

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

[this link](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/)  contains some tutorials for image processing and is useful for me, but my problem is it is too slow to process.Actually i would try to processing effect on image when sliding bar. Means when user scroll the slider based on that image processing is done. when image size is 70x70(30kb) it is ok for me(performance was good) but when its size is increasing it will take too much time to process.i have try to reduce the size of bitmap upto 40% using `bitmap.compress` , but still its size is too large to process.

- Also, will image processing time is depends on colors on image ?
- how to decrease the size of the image/bitmap so image processing not take too much time.
  is there any other way to processing bitmap fast or using above tutorial how i improve the performance?

Comment: Do a low resolution preview. Doing a preview at full res is not a good idea even on desktop computers. Image processing times should not be dependent on colors in the image in most known algorithms. I don't know what kind of data structure holds your pixel data. In general, I can say that in a past life, I've used (for example) every alternate or fourth line to do my previews, but for doing this, your data structure must be suitable enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will answer your questions, but hopefully it'll help you.

**A few ideas:**

1. **Do preview processing on a down-sized version of the original image.** This will make your processing considerably faster than having to do it on the original full resolution image.
2. **Only do processing when the user releases the slider.** If the application has to continuously process the image while the user is changing the value of the slider, it'll take a long time to process the image. Instead, only apply the image effects when the user has released the slider and selected a value. It'll speed up things considerably. I'm assuming you're using a [`SeekBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) - if so, you'd need to apply your image effects in the `onStopTrackingTouch()` method of the [`OnSeekBarChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html).
3. **Use `RGB_565` for your preview processing.** It uses less memory and should make things a bit faster.
4. **Optimize your code.** Carefully go through your code, and check if there's anything that could be done in a faster way. One of the usual problems in your case would be creating an excessive amount of `Bitmaps`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for replying. Yes down-sized image is faster than original image. you are right do the processing on release the slider fast, but requirement is processing on sliding. will RGB_565 reduce the quality of the image ?

Comment: Well, it's slightly lower quality, but if you only use it for the thumbnail preview, it should be just fine :)